# three.js memory management shader material

Tags: javascript, memory-leaks, three.js

I'm trying to create textual labels. I need to use shader material to better control the label during rendering.

I've noticed that the memory keeps increasing even though I clean up old labels.

I've created a jsfiddle example that is not unlike: https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_test_memory

The following code uses a canvas object to generate a texture, which contains the text to be depicted as a label:

Please be careful, these computations are heavy and make the tab quite unresponsive.

```js
var container;

var camera, scene, renderer;

var labels;   

var canvas;

init();
animate();

function init() {

  container = document.createElement( 'div' );
  document.body.appendChild( container );

  camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 60, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 10000 );
  camera.position.z = 200;

  scene = new THREE.Scene();

  renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
  renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
  renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
  container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

  labels = new THREE.Object3D();

  canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
  var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

  // get text metrics
  var fontface = 'Arial';
  var fontSize = 60;
  context.font = fontSize + "px " + fontface;

  var width = context.measureText(text).width;

  // add text
  var text = 'abcdef';
  canvas.width = width;
  canvas.height = fontSize*1.3;
  context.textAlign = "center";
  context.font = fontSize + "px " + fontface;
  context.fillStyle = "white";    
  context.fillText(text, canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2);
}

function createLabels() {       
  for(var i = 0; i < 10000 ; i++) {
    createTextMesh();
  }

  scene.add( labels );
}

function createTextMesh() {
  // canvas contents will be used for a texture
  var texture = new THREE.Texture(canvas);
  texture.needsUpdate = true;

  var uniforms = {
    text: {
      type: 't',
      value: texture
    }
  };

  var material = new THREE.ShaderMaterial( {
    uniforms: uniforms,
    vertexShader: document.getElementById( 'vertex-shader' ).textContent,
    fragmentShader: document.getElementById( 'fragment-shader' ).textContent
  } );

  var geometry = new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry(15, 15);

  var label = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );

  labels.add(label);
}

function clearLabels() {
  for(var i = 0; i < labels.children.length; i++) {
    var label = labels.children[i];

    if(label.material.uniforms) {
      label.material.uniforms.text.value.dispose();
    }
    label.material.dispose();
    label.geometry.dispose();

    labels.remove(label);     
  }

  scene.remove( labels );
}

function animate() {
  requestAnimationFrame( animate );
  render();
}

function render() {
  // build GL objects
  createLabels();

  renderer.render( scene, camera );

  // clean up 
  clearLabels();
}
```

```css
body {
  margin:0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/85/three.min.js"></script>     
<script id="fragment-shader" type="x-shader/x-fragment">
  uniform sampler2D text;

  varying vec2 vUv;

  void main() {
    vec4 finalColor = texture2D(text, vUv);   
    gl_FragColor = finalColor;
  }
</script>  
<script id="vertex-shader" type="x-shader/x-fragment">
  varying vec2 vUv;

  void main() {
    vUv = uv;
    vec4 mvPosition = modelViewMatrix * vec4( position, 1.0 );
    gl_Position = projectionMatrix * mvPosition;
  }
</script>   
<canvas></canvas>
```

You can use's chromes dev tools to evaluate the perceptual memory utilisation increase.

I'd recommend using something like Window's own task manager to see the memory increase.

You can decrease the label creation speed, although this will naturally mean that it will take longer for the tab do run out of memory.

Am I doing the resource clean-up wrongly?

Cheers

Comment: @marques: what exactly you want to achieve ?? can you please specify clearly.

Comment: the problem I'm trying to fix requires the application to update multiple text labels per minute. I noticed that after a while the tab would die, but couldn't understand why. I believe there's a memory leak somewhere and I've narrowed it down to this piece of three.js functionality.

Comment: Nope, there is a problem with your code. you use requestAnimationFrame function which continuously calls animate function and in that function, you use for loop which iterates 1000 times.

Comment: My problem is RAM usage, not speed. Reducing the iteration count to 1 from 10000 doesn't fix the problem, just makes the RAM usage grow slower.

Comment: ok let edit in your code and try that out.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/y10Low8u/

Comment: Can you modify your example to just run `createLabels` and `clearLabels` only once and see what happens?

Answer (score 1):

Don't create a new mesh 1000 times every tick, pool them.
Don't create a 1000 geometries that are all the same plane. This is probably the biggest culprit here. Create just one, ever, and pass it to meshes. 
Textures, im not so sure about that one. I think you're not supposed to create a new texture from the canvas context, create once and update canvas.

This will go away with the changes, but it's good to note that for performance you'd want to avoid creating that uniforms object in the loop as well.

**EDIT**

You do create a lot of stuff. Width of the label comes in as 263, and if three's console log is to be trusted, it's resized to 256x64. So you end up with 480mb of data, although, with the alpha channel it could be 600mb. I assume that your demo never even gets to the disposal part. It just crashed the browser on my end.

Three also complains about the textures being NPOT, so it attempts to write out ten thousand console logs.

Comment: This code snipped was designed to test the existence of a memory leak, and to do so in a quick way. It's not a real world scenario application. It was build to mimic the structure of: https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_test_memory.

Comment: I see, you're trying to stress test this and confirm that you're disposing of resources correctly. This seems to be the proper way of disposing of things.

Comment: I don't know much about this topic but could t be that something is just not releasing quick enough? You do issue a lot of GL commands with this code. With javascripts GC, if you're releasing objects correctly, it would just stall at some point, run the GC longer, and not crash? I imagine the GPU management is not part of this, that somehow it collides?

Comment: There must be a reason why the example is generating one texture, one geometry, one node and one material. 10k is quite a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Hi try out following code 
as I have added time gap in animate function which calls render function.

there is one variable fps currently 24, you can change it.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 <head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title>three.js - shader material memory leak</title>  
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
  <style>
   body {
    background:#fff;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    overflow:hidden;
   }
  </style>
 </head>
 <body>
  <script src="https://threejs.org/build/three.js"></script>     
  <script id="fragment-shader" type="x-shader/x-fragment">
   uniform sampler2D text;

   varying vec2 vUv;

   void main() {
    vec4 finalColor = texture2D(text, vUv);   
    gl_FragColor = finalColor;
   }
  </script>  
  <script id="vertex-shader" type="x-shader/x-fragment">
   varying vec2 vUv;

   void main() {
    vUv = uv;
    vec4 mvPosition = modelViewMatrix * vec4( position, 1.0 );
    gl_Position = projectionMatrix * mvPosition;
   }
  </script>   
  <script>
   var container,
                camera, scene, renderer,
                labels,
                canvas,
                lastTime, fps = 24;
   
   init();
   animate();

   function init() {

    container = document.createElement( 'div' );
    document.body.appendChild( container );

    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 60, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 10000 );
    camera.position.z = 200;

    scene = new THREE.Scene();

    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
    renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
    container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
    
    labels = new THREE.Object3D();
    
    canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

    // get text metrics
    var fontface = 'Arial';
    var fontSize = 60;
    context.font = fontSize + "px " + fontface;

    var width = context.measureText(text).width;

    // add text
    var text = 'abcdef';
    canvas.width = width;
    canvas.height = fontSize*1.3;
    context.textAlign = "center";
    context.font = fontSize + "px " + fontface;
    context.fillStyle = "white";    
    context.fillText(text, canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2);
   }

   function createLabels() {       
    for(var i = 0; i < 10000 ; i++) {
     createTextMesh();
    }
    
    scene.add( labels );
   }
   
   function createTextMesh() {
    // canvas contents will be used for a texture
    var texture = new THREE.Texture(canvas);
    texture.needsUpdate = true;
    
    var uniforms = {
     text: {
      type: 't',
      value: texture
     }
    };

    var material = new THREE.ShaderMaterial( {
     uniforms: uniforms,
     vertexShader: document.getElementById( 'vertex-shader' ).textContent,
     fragmentShader: document.getElementById( 'fragment-shader' ).textContent
    } );
    
    var geometry = new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry(15, 15);

    var label = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
    
    labels.add(label);
   }
   
   function clearLabels() {
    for(var i = 0; i < labels.children.length; i++) {
     var label = labels.children[i];

     if(label.material.uniforms) {
      label.material.uniforms.text.value.dispose();
     }
     label.material.dispose();
     label.geometry.dispose();
    
     labels.remove(label);     
    }
    
    scene.remove( labels );
   }
   // Add time gap render will call with 24 fps. or you can slow down speed to check.
   function animate() {
               var curTime = new Date();
                           if(lastTime === undefined || (Math.round(curTime - lastTime)/1000) >= fps)
                           { 
                       render();
                                   lastTime = curTime;
                           }
                           requestAnimationFrame( animate );
   }

   function render() {
    // build GL objects
    createLabels();

    renderer.render( scene, camera );

    // clean up 
    clearLabels();
   }

  </script>
  <div>
   <canvas width="1920" height="974" style="width: 1920px; height: 974px;"></canvas>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your code still generates a memory leak, and the tab still dies. It just takes longer to do so.